# Using Time in a conditional Statement in Powershell

Tags: powershell, time, conditional-statements

I'm trying to just get the groundwork for running some code with a time conditional. But I can't seem to grasp how to add time into the equation. Any Powershell people out there?

The `$EndDate` doesnt matter anymore. I just tried to use it as a way to understand how powershell uses conditional

```
$StartTime=(Get-Date)

$EndDate=[datetime]”00:00”


if ($StartDate -gt "00:00" -and $StartTime -lt "11:59")
{
Write-Host "It is time to work"
}
else 
{
Write-Host "it is time to go"
}

$StartTime
```

My code right now should say its time to go but should say its time to work because as of right now its only `11:56 AM ET`.

Comment: do you really need to test for midnite? if you check the _time_ part of any datetime object it will ALWAYS be in the range of 00:00:00 to 11:59:59 ... so just testing for "less than noon" seems to do what you need. something like `(Get-Date).TimeOfDay.Hours -lt 12` looks likely.

Comment: What is $StartDate?  Where is $EndDate used?

Comment: Apologeez. Im new to this Powershell device and haven't understood much of it yet. End Date is nothing anymore. The goal would be for the code to tell if at some point in time if its before noon or afternnon

Comment: If you used $starttime for both, it would work.  We don't know what $startdate is.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare against the time of day, use the `TimeOfDay` TimeSpan exposed by `[datetime]` - PowerShell will automatically convert the right-hand `"HH:mm"` string into a meaningful TimeSpan that can be compared against:

```
$StartTime = Get-Date

if($StartTime.TimeOfDay -gt "00:00" -and $StartTime.TimeOfDay -le "12:00"){
    # AM
}
else{
    # PM
}
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful. I did not know such a tool existed. would the get-service run on get-date be where you would normally find stuff like this?

Comment: @JonRansom `Get-Date |Get-Member` would have showed you that the `[datetime]` object has a `TimeOfDay` property :)

Comment: Found it! Most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

These two things are usually true.

```
(get-date) -gt '00:00'
True

(get-date) -lt '23:59'
True
```

Check for unset variables:

```
set-strictmode -v 1
```